# Python BeautifulSoup: How to navigate a table within multiple divs

Tags: python, json, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've searched through the forum and tutorial videos but I can't for the life of me figure this one out. I'm trying to scrape options information from barchart.com using BeautifulSoup, but can't get the table to appear in my soup. I've tried multiple parsers but can't get it to come up. The goal is to then put that information into a dataframe.

When inspecting the page source, the farthest I can get is . The table lies multiple generations in that tag. The table lies in .

soup.findAll doesn't work since the tag does not come up in the soup. Here is the location of the table:
[TableLocation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaZBw.png)

Sorry if the question is obvious, I'm new to this. Thanks

Current code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = requests.utils.default_headers()
headers.update({
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0',
})

# def get_options(ticker, date):
ticker = 'TSLA'
date = '2020-03-20'

webpage_response = requests.get(
    'https://www.barchart.com/stocks/quotes/' + str(ticker) + '/options?moneyness=allRows&expiration=' + str(date),
    headers=headers)

webpage = webpage_response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "lxml")


print(soup.prettify())

# find table from barchart.com
```

Comment: _soup.findAll doesn't work since the tag does not come up in the soup._ If that's the case then you can't get the data no matter what, right?

Answer (score 1):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv


def Main():
    with requests.Session() as req:
        headers = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0'}
        r = req.get(
            "https://www.barchart.com/stocks/quotes/TSLA/options?moneyness=allRows&expiration=2020-03-20", headers=headers)
        headers["X-XSRF-TOKEN"] = r.cookies.items()[0][1]
        headers["Accept"] = "application/json"
        r = req.get("https://www.barchart.com/proxies/core-api/v1/options/get?symbol=TSLA&fields=strikePrice%2ClastPrice%2CpercentFromLast%2CbidPrice%2Cmidpoint%2CaskPrice%2CpriceChange%2CpercentChange%2Cvolatility%2Cvolume%2CopenInterest%2CoptionType%2CdaysToExpiration%2CexpirationDate%2CtradeTime%2CsymbolCode%2CsymbolType&groupBy=optionType&expirationDate=2020-03-20&meta=field.shortName%2Cexpirations%2Cfield.description&raw=1", headers=headers).json()
        with open("lala.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(list(r["data"]["Call"][0].keys())[:-1])
            for data in r["data"]["Call"]:
                writer.writerow(list(data.values())[:-1])


Main()
```

Output: [check-online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/5c26c971ace943797ee548bd351a834f/lala.csv)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore, I'm getting error 400.

Comment: Okay, it should be: headers["X-XSRF-TOKEN"] = unquote(r.cookies.items()[0][1])

Answer (score 0):

If you choose a tag in the table and just search for it in your 'webpage' variable, it won't be there (at least it wasn't for me).

It looks like the content is dynamic, so I would use Selenium. I was able to find the table with the code below.

```
import time, os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# use google chrome
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# go to your website
driver.get('https://www.barchart.com/stocks/quotes/' + str(ticker) + '/options?moneyness=allRows&expiration=' + str(date))

# wait for all the dynamic content to load
time.sleep(1)

# soup it
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

# find the table body
soup.FindAll('tbody')
```